# PHP calendar with recurring events from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

**UPDATE:**
Below is my original question. See my answer to see how I solved it.

---

I am trying to populate my calendar with events from MySQL database table 'churchcal_events'. I might have one-time events for specific dates and recurring events that can be set for Every Monday, Every Other Thursday, or Every Month on Second Friday.

One-time events are no problem. And weekly events work (every week, every other). But an **every-month-event shows only on the first month, not on the months following**.

**churchcal_events table** - excluding fields that are not important to this question

```
+----+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| id | name           | recurring  | frequency | recur_type | recur_day  |
+----+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | Test Weekly    | 1          | 1         | W          | Sunday     |
| 2  | Test Bi-Weekly | 1          | 2         | W          | Monday     |
| 3  | Test Monthly   | 1          | 1         | M          | Friday     |
+----+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

**php code** - inside of a loop for each day of the month

```
//query all events
    $get_events = db_query("SELECT * FROM {churchcal_events}
    WHERE (MONTH(date) = :month AND YEAR(date) = :year AND DAY(date) = :day) OR
    (recurring = :recur AND recur_day LIKE :calendar_day)
    ORDER BY starttime",
    array(
      ':month' => $month,
      ':year' => $year,
      ':day' => $list_day,
      ':recur' => '1',
      ':calendar_day' => '%' . date('l', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year)) . '%',
    ));

    foreach($get_events as $event) {

      //see if events belong to this calendar
      $calendar_assign = db_query("SELECT * FROM {churchcal_assign} WHERE event_id = :event_id AND calendar_id = :cal_id",
      array(
        ':event_id' => $event->id,
        ':cal_id' => $cal_id,
      ));

      if($calendar_assign->rowCount() > 0) {

        //if recurring, see if event should be on this day
        if($event->recurring == '1') {

          $recur_day = $event->recur_day;
          $recur_freq = $event->frequency;
          $recur_type = $event->recur_type;

          $recur_start = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event->recur_start)));
          $recur_end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event->recur_end)));

          $recur_start->modify($recur_day);

          $recur_interval = new DateInterval("P{$recur_freq}{$recur_type}");
          $recur_period = new DatePeriod($recur_start, $recur_interval, $recur_end);

          foreach($recur_period as $recur_date) {

            if($recur_date->format('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year))) {

              $calendar .= calendar_event($event-id, $event->name, $event->starttime);

            }

          }

        }
```

**How can I make ID '3' from the example churchcal_events table show up the first Friday of every month?**

Comment: What's your db_query() function look like?

Comment: @cpattersonv1 it's the [Drupal 7 db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) function.

Comment: Have you checked your values for your variables like recur_period? Also From PHP doc: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Comment: Also, I would verify the date/time on the server running PHP. Sometimes you can get unexpected results when the server time is different than what you think it is...

Comment: @Revent The dates are correct like this.

Comment: Unsolicited advice from one who has gotten lost on a road like the one you are on:  Use Google Calendar for your church calendar, and embed it in your Drupal site. The folks at Google have worked out all the complex recurrences.

Comment: @OllieJones Thank you for your suggestion. I have embedded Google Calendars before. It is a good option. However, the customization of creating my own calendar module to tie in with other modules that will rely on it far exceeds the functionality of Google Calendars or at least the time that it would take to really learn the API. Read my answer for the solution I worked up. There may be more recurring event scenarios of which I haven't thought yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case anyone would like to do something similar, I will post the code that I wrote and tested within the last five hours.

I decided to convert my two tables into three, moving all of the recurring options to the third table:

**'churchcal_events'** - there are additional fields for event info that I haven't included here

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| id | name      | date       | starttime  | endtime    | recurring |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | Event 1   | 2013-04-01 | 10:30:00   | 12:00:00   | 0         |
| 2  | Event 2   |            | 14:00:00   | 15:00:00   | 1         |
| 3  | Event 3   |            | 09:00:00   |            | 1         |
| 4  | Event 4   |            | 19:00:00   | 21:00:00   | 1         |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

**'churchcal_assign'** - routes events to appropriate calendars (because there will be calendars for different departments throughout the website)

```
+----------+-------------+
| event_id | calendar_id | 
+----------+-------------+
| 1        | 1           |
| 2        | 1           |
| 3        | 1           |
| 4        | 1           |
+----------+-------------+
```

**'churchcal_recur_events'** - Here are the rules for each event's recurrence

```
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| event_id | frequency | recur_type | recur_day_num  | recur_day  | recur_start | recur_end |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2        | 1         | Week       | NULL           | Sunday     | NULL        | NULL      |
| 3        | 2         | Week       | NULL           | Wednesday  | 2013-04-01  | NULL      |
| 4        | 2         | Month      | third          | Friday     | 2013-04-01  | NULL      |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**New Code (PHP)** - This is in a day loop

```
    //query all events
    $get_events = db_query("SELECT * FROM {churchcal_events ce, churchcal_recur_events cre}
    WHERE (MONTH(ce.date) = :month AND YEAR(ce.date) = :year AND DAY(ce.date) = :day) OR
    (ce.id = cre.event_id AND ce.recurring = :recur AND cre.recur_day = :calendar_day)
    ORDER BY starttime",
    array(
      ':month' => $month,
      ':year' => $year,
      ':day' => $list_day,
      ':recur' => '1',
      ':calendar_day' => date('l', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year)),
    ));



    foreach($get_events as $event) {

      //see if events belong to this calendar
      $calendar_assign = db_query("SELECT * FROM {churchcal_assign} WHERE event_id = :event_id AND calendar_id = :cal_id",
      array(
        ':event_id' => $event->id,
        ':cal_id' => $cal_id,
      ));

      if($calendar_assign->rowCount() > 0) {

        //one-time events
        if(($event->recurring != '1') && ($single_event_id != $event->id)) {
          $calendar .= calendar_event($event->id, $event->name, $event->starttime);
          $single_event_id = $event->id;
          //$calendar .= $single_event_id;
        }

          //monthly recurring events
          if(($event->recur_type == 'Month') && ($event->recurring == '1')
          //day is on or before end date
          && (($event->recur_end >= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year))) || ($event->recur_end == '0000-00-00') || ($event->recur_end == NULL))
          //day is on or after start date
          && (($event->recur_start <= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year))) || ($event->recur_start == '0000-00-00') || ($event->recur_start == NULL))
          //day is equal to date of recurrence, i.e. first friday, third monday, etc
          && ($year . date('m', strtotime($year . '/' . $month . '/' . $list_day)) . $list_day == date('Ymj', strtotime($event->recur_day_num . ' ' . $event->recur_day . ' of ' . date('F', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year)) . ' ' . $year)))
          //day is in agreement with month frequency, i.e. every month, every other, etc. from start date
          && ($month % $event->frequency == date('m', strtotime($event->recur_start)) % $event->frequency)) {
            $calendar .= calendar_event($event->id, $event->name, $event->starttime);
          }


          //weekly recurring events
          if(($event->recur_type == 'Week') && ($event->recurring == '1')
          //day is on or before end date
          && (($event->recur_end >= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year))) || ($event->recur_end == '0000-00-00') || ($event->recur_end == NULL))
          //day is on or after start date
          && (($event->recur_start <= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year))) || ($event->recur_start == '0000-00-00') || ($event->recur_start == NULL))
          //day is in agreement with week frequency, i.e. every week, every other, etc. from start date
          && (date('W', strtotime($month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year)) % $event->frequency == date('W', strtotime($event->recur_start)) % $event->frequency)) {

            $calendar .= calendar_event($event->id, $event->name, $event->starttime);

          }

      }

    }
```

If you are not creating this in a Drupal module like I am, you can replace 'db_query()' with your own database query function like PHP's default 'mysql_query()';