# Can I create a way for two events to be swapped using Drupal's Calendar module functionality?

Tags: drupal, calendar, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Suppose there are two recurring events that have already been defined in the Event Calendar - one happens every Monday at 11:00 am, the other every Friday at 9:00 am. I want to create functionality to be able to swap the two events, both temporarily (one-off and till a certain date) and permanently. Is there a combination of modules that I can deploy to enable such functionality? Do I need to write code for this?

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like this has some relation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753827/php-calendar-with-recurring-events-from-mysql-database/15758346#15758346

Comment: That's only for creating events with recurring dates. I need to be able to swap events around...